# How to specify Bootstrap grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, grid-layout

I have a customized bootstrap setup to use 960 grid instead of the default width. I have this HTML using the bootstrap grid:

```
<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          </div>
</div>
```

However on a specific page I need to be exact in their width, for instance I need the first row to be 280 pixels, the second 500 pixels and the third 160 pixels. How can I do that using the bootstrap grid so that it still will be responsive for mobile devices?

Comment: Probably will have to use custom css classes and media query for that

Comment: For that particular page, you can attach a custom CSS file and overwrite the CSS properties. Note:Overwriting width, padding, margins of Bootstrap requires the usage of !important tag.